# How to fix PHP8 fatal error: ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method?

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8

I have been using a WordPress plugin which is **no longer maintained** (livecom). I recently updated the website to PHP8, but this plugin, so long as it is active, now causes a fatal WordPress error. I'd prefer to keep the plugin, even if I have to manually 'patch' it for the time being.

I believe I can trace the error to this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method
```

I note this doesn't explicitly tell me the line of PHP code which is causing the error - the lines the PHP error log references are in the /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php, /wp-settings.php and /wp-load.php files, which I don't believe are themselves directly causing the issue.

Inspecting some of the plugin code, I note it does the following:

```
function init()
{
    OmAlb_LiveCom_HookHandlers::add_shortcode();
}
```

There are numerous examples of code like the above. Is this causing the fatal error? If so, how should the code be manually restructured to prevent the fatal errors?

EDIT - This is the full error:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method OmAlb_LiveCom::plugins_loaded() cannot be called statically in /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()<br>n
> #1 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()\n
> #2 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-settings.php(480): do_action()\n
> #3 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-config.php(101): require_once('...')\n
> #4 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...')\n
> #5 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('...')\n
> #6 /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/index.php(17): require('...')\n
> #7 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/<>/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308', referer: https://<>/<>`

Comment: _the lines the PHP error log references ....._ So show us the error messages and then we can see where the error is, I assume the stack trace is causing you confusion

Comment: _"Is this causing the fatal error?"_ - no, because that is a direct method call, `call_user_func_array` is not even involved at that point.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the full error from the log. I was trying to be succinct.

Comment: If the plugin is in the plugin repo on wordpress.org, or its source code is available someplace else, please [edit] your question to tell us where it is.

Comment: @O.Jones unfortunately it was offered as a premium paid-for plugin some years ago.

Comment: "Years ago" sounds like a good reason to either ask the maintainers for an updated version, or search for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

[call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) expects parameter one to be a [Callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). Since the error is specifically telling you you need to pass a non-static method, you will need to implement either a user-defined function, such as

```
function myCallback() {
    MyClass::myMethod();
}
```

or an instance-level method if you have an instance within your reach or an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Since the plugin is no longer maintained, you need not to worry about future updates and compatibility with them, so you can edit your plugin yourself. If you need further help, you will need to share the relevant part of the plugin you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your traceback with the eye of a WordPress dev, #0 and #1 are in the hooks subsystem -- the subsystem delivering callbacks to code in plugins and themes. WordPress lives and dies by the hooks subsystem. In your case it, umm, died.

That hooks subsystem is invoked with this line in wp-settings.php:480.

```
do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );
```

That probably means your offending plugin has a line like this someplace in it

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'OmAlb_LiveCom::plugins_loaded' );
```

There may be more parameters in that add_action line.

That line probably lies within the class definition for `OmAlb_LiveCom`. And, that same class definition probably has a function definition something like this:

```php
public function plugins_loaded () {
   /* Some code here. */
}
```

That `function plugins_loaded` must be a static function to match your add_action call.  That's what your error complains about.

If this works with php 7.x, go back and use it. If you can change the code of that plugin somehow, you might try some things:

You could try changing the `add_action()` call to this, to allow the hook to call a member function in the class.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [$this, 'plugins_loaded'] );
```

Or you could redefine `plugins_loaded` as a static function and use this:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded','OmAlb_LiveCom::plugins_loaded' );
```